# Тест аутентификации: роверить залогинился ли пользователь или нет

Tags: python, django

Помогите, пожалуйста, проверить залогинился ли пользователь или нет. вот моя попытка:

test.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class TestTemplatePage(TestCase):
    def set_up(self):
        self.client = Client()
        user = User.objects.create('qqq', 'qqq')

    def test_logged_in(self):
        response = self.client.login(username='qqq', password='qqq')
        self.assertEqual(response, True)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app_drummersaransk',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'views.login', name='login', ),                   
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', 'views.user_personal', name='user_personal', ),
)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required     
def user_personal(request, id):     
    try:
        entries_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id=id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/page_error404/')

    entries_user = User.objects.get(id=id)

    path_pk = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        path_pk = id
        user_id = int(request.user.pk)

        if request.POST.get('action', '') == 'add':                 
            q = Friends.get_entry(user_id=user_id, friend_id=path_pk)

            if q == False:              
                Friends.set_entry(user_id=user_id, friend_id=path_pk)   #add

        if request.POST.get('action', '') == 'delete':      
            try:
                Friends.get_entry(user_id=user_id, friend_id=path_pk)   #del
            except:
                pass            
            else:           
                Friends.del_entry(user_id=user_id, friend_id=path_pk)

    t = loader.get_template('user_personal.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'login': entries_user.username,
        'entries_user_profile': entries_user_profile,
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

несмотря на то, что существует пользователь с логином qqq и паролем qqq, в консоль выводится следующее сообщение:

```
c:\Python33\django_projects\drummersaransk_new>python manage.py test app_drummer
saransk
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_logged_in (app_drummersaransk.tests.TestTemplatePage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\django_projects\drummersaransk_new\app_drummersaransk\tests.
py", line 26, in test_logged_in
    self.assertEqual(response, True)
AssertionError: False != True

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.046s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 2):

`User.objects.create('qqq', 'qqq')` создает НЕ "пользователя с именем qqq и паролем qqq. Прочтите про дополнительные методы менеджера User в документации.